# php: best way to assign 10 times the same symbol (space) to a variable

Tags: php, string

We have

```
$symb="_";

$num=10;
```

We want `$ten_symbs` to be exactly `"__________"; // ten symbols "_".`
Whats the fastest and/or the best way to assign ten "_" to `$ten_symbs`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[str_repeat()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php):

```
$symbol = '_';
$num    = 10;
echo str_repeat($symbol, $num);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) as:

```
$ten_symbs = str_repeat($symb, $num);
```

You can also do:

```
$ten_symbs = str_pad('',$num,$symb);
```

But the fist option is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

look for str_repeat() here: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.str-repeat.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$ten_symbs = '';
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) {
   $ten_symbs .= $symb;
}
```